# EF Core 2.1 Aggregated values and Where clause

Tags: aggregate, ef-core-2.1

Is there a proper way to do Count of child items of an entity and filter by this value

The way i'm trying to do it right now

```
var seed = context.Items.Select(x => new {
  count = x.ChildItems.Count()
};

seed = seed.Where(x => x.count > 0);
```

As a result I see in logs that

The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
And it will create count query for each row!!

Am i doing something wrong or this is not possible in EF CORE 2.1

Comment: Can't reproduce in EF Core 2.1.1 - not getting such warning and the sample query translates to single SQL. Does your query contains something not shown in here?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the following:

```
var seed = context.Items.Include(x => x.ChildItems).Where(x => x.ChildItems.Count() > 0).ToList();
```